# XAML Path element - how to make soft corners

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, xaml

I'm trying to figure out how to set Data property of the Path element to get soft corners of this type:

[image]

Right now I have only sharp corners like this:

[image]

I tried playing with ellipses, but I can't get what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Segments of a path have a IsSmoothJoin property, defaulting to false. I have never tried it but it seems to be a good candidate.

Another idea is to use a PolyLine (instead of a Path, if that's OK in your case). PolyLine has the StrokeLineJoin property, of type PenLineJoin, which allow for rounded corners. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc294765.aspx), under Strokes, for the possibilities.

Edit: added the following:
Actually, the StrokeLineJoin property comes from the Shape class, and Path is a subclass of Shape, so you can use this property directly in the Path instance.

Comment: Thanks Timores, I was looking for something like this. Although the corner radius is still a bit smaller from what I need, I can work with this.

Comment: Please have a look at the added paragraph at the end.

Answer (score 1):

There is a StrokeLineJoin, StrokeStartLine and a StrokeEndLine properties on the path tag that you can use for this effect, and then you can use the rounded effects on sharp corners within the path, or at the end of the path.

Comment: please, provide more information ,if you can, an example is always good received.