# How to convert whole XAML file to System.Windows.Media.Geometry object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, type-conversion

How to: `XAML` -> [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) `System.Windows.Media.Geometry` ?

I want to create vector image *(for example, in Inkscape)*, save it to XAML, than take whole file *(from the very first "<" symbol to the very last symbol ">")*, put in [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23) string, and then to make `System.Windows.Media.Geometry` object.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40019463/rounded-corners-for-path) way is very good, it works perfect:

```
 System.Windows.Media.Geometry g = Geometry.Parse("M 263,99 ... Z");
```

But, it fails *(in my hands)* with multi-line paths, fills, and other symbols.

UPD:

```
string sourse_xaml_str =
```

`@"`

```xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--This file is compatible with Silverlight-->
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" Name="svg8" Width="210" Height="297">
  <Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="0"/>
  </Canvas.RenderTransform>
  <Canvas.Resources/>
  <!--Unknown tag: sodipodi:namedview-->
  <!--Unknown tag: metadata-->
  <Canvas Name="layer1">
    <Path xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Name="path10" Fill="#FFFF5555" StrokeThickness="0.26458332" Data="m 74.083331 126.9107 -10.873824 18.802 9.324097 19.61673 -21.241956 -4.53148 -15.775318 14.92964 -2.254427 -21.6026 -19.073781 -10.38971 19.848644 -8.81966 3.987074 -21.35084 14.521563 16.15176 z"/>
  </Canvas>
</Canvas>
```

`";`

```csharp
System.Windows.Media.Geometry top_menu_item_icon = XamlReader.Parse( sourse_xaml_str ) as System.Windows.Media.Geometry;
Console.WriteLn( XamlReader.Parse( sourse_xaml_str ).ToString() );
```

Results:

1. `top_menu_item_icon` == `null`
2. `WriteLn()` show this: `System.Windows.Controls.Canvas`

So, it still not works for me.

Comment: I'm not familiar with how Inkscape outputs XAML, but have you tried [XamlReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910814/loading-xaml-at-runtime) to load a XAML file at runtime? Could you post the contents of a small example XAML file from Inkscape?

Comment: Thank You for idea. Need to pack everything inside one only `C#` file. That's why I am going to put whole file in string manually. I played with `XamlReader`, but can't let it to read from string.

Comment: Use [XamlReader.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.markup.xamlreader.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Markup_XamlReader_Parse_System_String_)

Comment: Sorry, still not works for me. Tried it before, trying now, but no result. Can't find any info, also, about how to convert `Canvas` to `Geometry`